# `tableView` moves up while selecting Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, swift2

In my View Controller I have a `tableView` and overtime I select my cell my `tableview` moves a bit upside I don't know why its happening, I tried to figure out why is it happening but I got nothing. Below is my code if any body can find out whats wrong then it'll be so helpful for me.

**Outlets and Variables:**

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var headerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var verticalSpaceConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
var lastVerticalOffset: CGFloat = 0
```

in `ViewDidLoad:`

```
tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: headerViewOriginalHeight, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = tableView.contentInset
lastVerticalOffset = tableView.contentOffset.y


...........

footerView.addSubview(footerLabel)
footerView.addSubview(footerRetryButton)
footerView.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)

self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView
```

**Delegates:**

```
extension myViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return reviewsArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! TagDetailTableViewCell
        ..............................
        return cell
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        if  indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
            return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        } else {
            return 100
        }

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        tableView.beginUpdates()

        if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
            selectedIndexPath = NSIndexPath()
        }else {
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath
        }
        tableView.endUpdates()

        print( "tableView ORIIGN Y AFETER ", tableView.contentOffset.y)

        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .None
        self.tableView.separatorStyle = .SingleLine


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are remove the code of tableView Reload inSide the DidSelect method. Remove  `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()`, Now you are only reload Single Cell of TableView.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

      if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
        selectedIndexPath = NSIndexPath()
      }else {
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath
      }

     NSArray* rowsToReload = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil];
     [myUITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:rowsToReload withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

     self.tableView.separatorStyle = .None
     self.tableView.separatorStyle = .SingleLine
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `tableView.beginUpdates()` and `tableView.endUpdates()` from `didselectrow` method. You not need to use it in this context!

Manage array to keep track of selected row and manage `cellforrow` accordingly and reload table from `didselectrow`.

or in your `viewDidload` try

```
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Comment: hey man , thanks for responding , i'm using  `tableView.beginUpdates()` because i'm changing the height of selected row and  `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` didn't worked